# how to cover an image by another transparent color of same size as image

Tags: html, css

I want to cover an image by another transparent color or another image so that i will be able to view image contents clearly from covered color

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: `I want to` is generally a bad idea to ask a question especially when your question has a missing `here is what i have tried so far` section....

Comment: taken a div with an image inside it
now cover that image with another color....which must be trasparent

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/JLBaZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following example :

```
div {
    background: url( ..) no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

IF you want to cover an image with a transparent overlay or an image you can achieve this with pseudo elements

http://jsfiddle.net/wef8M/

But if you want to have some content in the overlay you have to create a wrapper to wrap the  background img.